# Get a list of child pages via a function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a list of child pages to display on the parent page via wordpress. The best way I can describe what I am trying to do is if you are on the about page (/about) but you want to go to the meet the team page (/about/meet-the-team) when you are on the about page it should then display a link to the meet the team page.

I have this code at the moment

```
function getPagesHierarchy() {
    $pagesQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'   => 0,
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    )) ;
    if ($pagesQuery->have_posts()) {
        while($pagesQuery->have_posts()) {
            $pagesQuery->the_post() ;
            the_title() ;
            echo '<br>' ;
        }
    }
    
}
```

What this is doing is it is getting a structure of the parent pages like this image shows below
[image]

This is currently getting all the parent pages which is fine however I also need it to display that parent pages children under it.  so for example it would be something like this;

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated if I can give anything else to assist in what I am trying to achieve please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_list_pages()` and pass in the parent page ID with `child_of` to get its children. You can refer to [the WP docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) for more info.
So that'd look something like

```
wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of' => $parentId
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/)

```
function getPagesHierarchy() {
    
    $pages = get_pages(array('parent' => 0)); 
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        echo $page->post_title;
        echo '<br>' ;
        $child_pages = get_pages(array( 'child_of' => $page->ID)); 
        foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {
            echo $child_page->post_title;
            echo '<br>' ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so this seems to work a bit to well it seems to get every child page on the website not the ones corelating to the parent page which you are on could you help with this? it also then begins to add in all parent pages after some child so im not sure what is happening with it

Comment: so you just want to list the child pages of that specific page?

Comment: the end goal is to have a list of all parent pages and then when you click into a parent page you still see the other parent pages but the children for the active parent are then showed below that active parent.